# Eclipse with Private Git Server

Tags: eclipse, git

I am trying to configure eclipse in Windows to properly work with my private remote git server that I have set up. The Git server is running on Ubuntu and has git installed and properly working, however all of the tutorials I see only cover github and bitbase. Any tutorials that talk about private git servers assume you are committing with ssh and not through eclipse. I have tried following the basic tutorials, but I am kind of at a loss here. Are there any good tutorials out there that cover eclipse working with private git remote repositories?

Edit:

On the ubuntu server I have a username 'git' and I already have git installed.

Step by step of what I did to set up the repo on the ubuntu server:

```
cd to the home directory of 'git.'
mkdir 'gittest.git'
cd gittest.git
git init --bare
```

Then in eclipse, I have a java project called "GitTest" which just has a package "gitTest" and 1 class file "GitTest."

I right click on the project -> team -> share project -> git -> create a new local repository for the project.

After that I go to the new git repository on the Git Repositories sub menu. I click the drop-down arrow on the GitTest repo and go to Remotes -> Remote name: origin; configure push -> URL is ssh://x.x.x.x/home/git/gittest.git ; Host is the IP of the server, and repo path is /home/git/gittest.git and the protocol is set to 'ssh.' I also have the username 'git' and is password down in the username and password field.

After that I go to remotes -> origin -> push. It brings up the push results window which just says "master:master[new branch]" and in the bottom window says "repository ssh://git@x.x.x.x/home/git/gittest.git."

This makes it look like it went successfully, but I cannot find the gittest class file anywhere in the gittest.git directory on the server. Where would it be?

Comment: Which Eclipse version are you using? I haven't used EGit with SSH on Windows but it works fine on Linux. Have you tried these [steps](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration)?

Comment: Yup. Initially when I set up the git server on ubuntu, I did generate some ssh keys. Do I need to copy those keys from the server and put them on my local windows machine? Also, if I try to commit/push, I don't get any errors and it says it went through fine, but when I go and look at the server I dont see the committed files anywhere in the repository.

Comment: Unless you want to check that you are connecting to the right server you will not need the keys from the server. Could you give a step by step summary how you configured EGit?

Comment: You've gone through http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide ?

Comment: `--bare` repository don't checkout files in a folder. So you won't be able to see files on the server if the repo you push too is a bare one. To test if everything went ok, just clone the project in another directory and check if the file is there.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias: Or `cd` into the bare repository and use `git log` to see if the commits are there.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias So I should be able to just copy the project in eclipse with no class files, and fetch to class files from the git server to see if it worked?

Comment: I tried your steps locally and it worked. If the data is in your remote repository you should be able to clone from it (or as you said create another project, set up the remote and pull from it). Another way is to import the project from a remote repository, which will also create a local repository and store the remote as origin (it is equivalent to `git clone <remote>`).